# What is wrong with my quantum grover's algorithm?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

I am trying to create Grover's algorithm in quantum programming with Qiskit to find the target binary string `010`.

This is my process :

1. Apply a Hadamard gate to 4 qubits (3 for the binary string and 1 for the target qubit)
2. I create a circuit for the oracle. I use $X$ gates to flip the 1st and 3rd input qubits - meaning only when they are 0 will they become 1. Following this, I used a $CX$ gate with all 3 input qubits as control and the target qubit as the target. This means it should flip the target when the 3 input qubits are one, only possible if it's my target string `010`
3. I created a grover diffusion circuit
4. I applied the oracle and grover diffusion iteratively creating a circuit.
5. I created a circuit designed to measure the first 3 qubits.
6. I made a graph counting the results.

When I tried a similar algorithm with 2 qubits, I got `11` only in my counts graph. I haven't been able to do that with 3-qubit strings like `010`. I tried changing iterations and experimenting with how gates like the `cz([0,1,2])` are applied by making it 3 individual (`cz(0,2)`...etc). I feel like there's something wrong logically.

Any help is appreciated.

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.h(range(4))

num_iterations = 16 # Set the number of iterations

# Oracle for marking |01⟩ state
oracle = QuantumCircuit(4)
oracle.x(0)
oracle.x(2)
oracle.cx([0,1,2],3)

oracle.x(0)
oracle.x(2)

# Grover diffusion operator
grover_diffusion = QuantumCircuit(4)
grover_diffusion.h(range(4))
grover_diffusion.z(3)
grover_diffusion.cz([0,1,2],3)
grover_diffusion.h(range(3))

# Apply the oracle and Grover diffusion iteratively
for _ in range(num_iterations):
    qc.compose(oracle, inplace=True)
    
    # Apply the Grover diffusion operator
    qc.compose(grover_diffusion, inplace=True)

    
sv_sim = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = sv_sim.run(qc).result()
statevec = result.get_statevector()
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(statevec, prefix="|\\psi\\rangle =")

#Measure circuit
measurer = QuantumCircuit(4,3)
measurer.measure([0,1,2],[0,1,2])

qc.compose(measurer, inplace=True)

# Measure the qubits
#qc.measure([0,1,2],[0,1,2])

qasm_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = qasm_sim.run(qc).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

Comment: please if you cross-post, edit the question to link the two posts together to avoid duplication of effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- You incorrectly assume that `qc.cx([0, 1, 2], 3)` is an $X$ gate on the fourth qubit controlled off the first three ones, but it's not. Instead, it's three $\mathsf{C}-X$ gates, with the fourth qubit being their target and their control qubit being one of the first three. This mistake is present in both `oracle` and `grover_diffusion`.
- The optimal number of iterations in Grover's algorithm depends only on the number of solutions (here, 1) and the number of qubits (here, 3). The number of iterations with a single solution using $n$ qubits is given by:
  $$N=\left\lfloor\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{2^n}\right\rfloor$$
- You apply the diffusion operator on the fourth qubit, which is supposed to stay in the $|-\rangle$ state to use it for phase kickback.
- The diffusion operator is supposed to be a layer of $H$ gates followed by a layer of $X$ gates, followed by a multi-controlled-$Z$, followed by a layer of $X$ gates, followed by a layer of $H$ gates. Here, you're missing the $X$ gates layers.

All in all, we end up with the following code:

```python
from math import pi, sqrt

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.h(range(4))
# Fourth qubit in |-> state
qc.z(3)

num_iterations = int(pi * sqrt(2 ** 3) / 4) # Set the number of iterations

# Oracle for marking |01⟩ state
oracle = QuantumCircuit(4)
oracle.x(0)
oracle.x(2)
oracle.mcx([0,1,2], 3)

oracle.x(0)
oracle.x(2)

# Grover diffusion operator
# We still make it acting on 4 qubits so that we don't change the rest of the code, but
# we're leaving the fourth qubit alone.
grover_diffusion = QuantumCircuit(4)
grover_diffusion.h(range(3))
grover_diffusion.x(range(3))
# For some reason Aer doesn't like the ccz gate, so we build one from a ccx using the Z = HXH relation
# grover_diffusion.ccz(0, 1, 2)
grover_diffusion.h(2)
grover_diffusion.ccx(0, 1, 2)
grover_diffusion.h(2)
grover_diffusion.x(range(3))
grover_diffusion.h(range(3))

# Apply the oracle and Grover diffusion iteratively
for _ in range(num_iterations):
    qc.compose(oracle, inplace=True)
    
    # Apply the Grover diffusion operator
    qc.compose(grover_diffusion, inplace=True)

    
sv_sim = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = sv_sim.run(qc).result()
statevec = result.get_statevector()
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(statevec, prefix="|\\psi\\rangle =")

#Measure circuit
measurer = QuantumCircuit(4,3)
measurer.measure([0,1,2],[0,1,2])

qc.compose(measurer, inplace=True)

# Measure the qubits
#qc.measure([0,1,2],[0,1,2])

qasm_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = qasm_sim.run(qc).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

which then plots this result:
[image: Histogram of results clearly showing the marked state]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and I get it now!